# Is there any research about how risky it is to have a circular saw?

Tags: electrical, wood, safety

Is there any research about how risky it is to have a circular saw? I want to buy my first one. I already watched many YouTube safety tips. But, I am still concerned. Is there specific data on the percentage of people who were injured while using this saw?

Comment: Personal opinion but as power tools go a circular saw is pretty safe. The biggest risk is probably getting something thrown in your eyes so safety googles are a must.

Comment: Most people who are injured using them, usually are not paying attention, using a damaged saw, or drunk/high.  Pay attention, watch where the saw is compared to your body parts, have the wood fixed/clamped in place before cutting(don't hold in one hand and cut), and keep saw and safety guards maintain.

Comment: In addition to what @crip659 says, only expose as much of the blade that is necessary to make the cut.  Let the saw do the cutting, don't push it faster than it wants to go. You'll love it.

Comment: If you are curious and concerned about safety, as you are, you will be above the average of the statistics (if they exist).   If you only use it rarely and therefore can be very focused and purposeful about safety, never becoming casual about it, that will put you further above the average. If you also buy other tools that are more appropriate to some jobs, and only use the circular saw for its ideal purposes, you'll climb even higher.

Comment: Not as risky as a jointer.

Comment: No numbers, but I'm pretty sure saw accidents happen when people do stupid things, like pin the guard back, fail to secure their workpiece, cut things that are overhead, and let the kerf pinch the blade while cutting because the offcut has pressure under it.

Comment: You know what else will drive you up above the average statistical injury?  Do something NOBODY does: Read all those "boring" safety instructions at the front of the manual.  Then read the entire manual before plugging in the saw and try all its features while unplugged.   Then use the saw for a few simple cuts in ideal circumstances, then read the whole manual again.

Comment: @jay613 Do yow mean below the statistical? Or are you cynical?
Please see my newer question about my plans for the saw. I would appreciate to know what do you think
https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/225274/is-it-safe-to-use-circular-saw-without-workbench-sawhourse

Comment: I mean "above average" in a positive sense.   I should have used "below" if I was answering your question properly as in "likeliness to be injured".  sorry.  Being safety conscious, reading, preparing, using for appropriate tasks and remaining focused will each contribute to making you less likely to be injured.  At some point you should stop worrying about statistics and more about how to get from very safe to super safe.   I'll take a stab at your new question.

Comment: Are there no other saws that will do the job you need to do?  I have never had need of a circular saw.  I tend to go for radial arm saws, or for small/infrequent work an oscillating saw.

Comment: Aminadav, if you go through the things mentioned here they are the same as the advice I gave on your other question. I have never met a builder that did not use a circular saw. Have I seen them get hurt. Rarely, usually doing something stupid. I have seen more hospital trips due to nail guns than circular saws. I have worn out several high end worm drive “skill” saws and 3 or 4 battery saws. not just dead batteries but worn the bushings out. With all that cutting no problems to speak of. Set your depth of cut, let the saw do the work and cut straight lines. Keep body parts away from saw path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safety instructions are available from many government bodies, e.g

http://www.safework.sa.gov.au/workplaces/plant-tools-and-vehicles/circular-saws

Regret I cannot cut and paste part of the article, not correct to quote only part of the article.