# Is it safe to use circular saw without workbench or saw horse?

Tags: electrical, safety, saw, circular-saw

[image]

I'm building a chicken coop, and I want to build it in-place using a cordless circular saw. I did not purchase the saw yet, until now I've used a Jigsaw, but for that I need to take it down that will be very slow.

I want to use the circular saw without removing the wood. Is it safe?

In all YouTube videos I watched I never seen someone using it without a table, workbench or saw horse. Is it safe?

Comment: If it is not clear my plans, I can make a better drawing/explanation.

Comment: Hopefully your artistry with a saw is better than with a pen.  :).  Ok sorry .....

Comment: You really need to read the sawhorse chapter in this book... https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/579156.Tools_of_the_Trade

Comment: People freehand circular saws all the time. If you have to ask then you're not one of them.

Comment: @jay613 It's not a pen. Google Canvas. Not easy to paint with Apple touch....

Comment: It was just meant to be funny but ok ... https://www.udemy.com/course/digital-art-101-from-beginner-to-pro/    You can become a defter drafter and a safer sawer all in one project :)

Answer (score 7):

Based on the project (chicken coup) and the very coarse drawing I think a reciprocating saw would be more appropriate and safer if you really need to cut it in place after installation. (But why?)

In the picture I think you have the top beam extending out over its support and you are cutting it to length.  As pictured it could pinch the saw as you cut it from the bottom up and then send the spinning saw towards your body.

You need a flat surface to hold the circular saw against and guide it.   If the coup is sturdy you could use its frame for that purpose, once fully built.

A better approach would be to cut the pieces to length on a more stable surface before assembling.  IT doesn't have to be fancy.  You can place a piece on the ground protruding out over the edge of a stair or ledge, and stand on it.  Then the saw is guided by the piece itself, you're cutting from the top, and your body is above and aside from the line of cut.

Comment: +1, but don't forget the handsaw as an alternative to even the reciprocating saw, it's a great tool, needs a bit more room to work, but it's a lot more forgiving, and WAAAY faster than the OP's jigsaw.

Comment: Good point.   Can't tell the size of the project from the Question but if it's just cutting several 2x4s to length a hand saw may indeed be the best choice, and for me certainly would be as I do not own any battery powered saw.  I also don't own any chickens but if I did I'd want them FAR from the house!

Answer (score 3):

Circ saws are dangerous. Using horses and tables mitigates some dangers.

Just a heads up, cordless circ saws suck power, you may need a whole set of batteries and chargers.

A cordless reciprocating saw (sawzall) might be better suited to your needs.

Answer (score 3):

Using a circular saw in place can be as safe or dangerous as on saw horses or on a bench, it’s how you handle it   Set the blade depth to just slightly deeper than the material you are cutting. Move forward at the saws cutting rate don’t force it and cut in a straight line or the saw may kick back.
So in ether case the saw can be dangerous. I use circular saws in place quite often when the blade is full time for a new one pushing a dull blade is how some accidents happen